# python tkinter checkbox sets run parallel

Tags: python, tkinter

I define two sets of Checkboxes, both with output to a separate List. The code runs, opens correctly a window with two Checkboxes. However, when I check in one set, it also checks the other one, too. Any idea?

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

n2_hit = range (4)
n1_hit = range (4)

self = Frame()

self.underframe = Frame()

self.underframe.n2e  = Frame(self.underframe, bd = 2, relief = RIDGE)
c_n2_0 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n2e, variable = n2_hit[0])
c_n2_0.pack (side=LEFT)
c_n2_1 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n2e, variable = n2_hit[1])
c_n2_1.pack (side=LEFT)
c_n2_2 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n2e, variable = n2_hit[2])
c_n2_2.pack (side=LEFT)
c_n2_3 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n2e, variable = n2_hit[3])
c_n2_3.pack (side=LEFT)
self.underframe.n2e.pack (side=LEFT)

self.underframe.n1e  = Frame(self.underframe, bd = 2, relief = RIDGE)
c_n1_0 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n1e, variable = n1_hit[0])
c_n1_0.pack (side=LEFT)
c_n1_1 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n1e, variable = n1_hit[1])
c_n1_1.pack (side=LEFT)
c_n1_2 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n1e, variable = n1_hit[2])
c_n1_2.pack (side=LEFT)
c_n1_3 = Checkbutton (self.underframe.n1e, variable = n1_hit[3])
c_n1_3.pack (side=LEFT)
self.underframe.n1e.pack (side=LEFT)

self.underframe.pack (side=TOP)

self.pack ()
```

Comment: This is happening because `n1_hit[0]` and `n2_hit[0]` are both referring to the same thing (even though they are in different lists).  The approach to fix this will vary depending on what you are trying to achieve down the road.  The intended use of the `variable` argument for a Checkbutton is an `IntVar()`, so you'll probably want to look into adding those to your lists and then setting them with `onvalue=` and `offvalue=`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should read more about tkiner also I think you should use another programming paradigm for example: Object-oriented programming (OOP).

Here I put a code with the functionality that you want:

```
    from tkinter import *
    class Checkbar(Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
          Frame.__init__(self, parent)
          self.vars = []
          for pick in picks:
             var = IntVar()
             chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
             chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
             self.vars.append(var)
       def state(self):
          return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)



  if __name__ == '__main__':
           root = Tk()
           lng = Checkbar(root, ['op1', 'op2','op3' ])
           tgl = Checkbar(root, ['op_1','op_2'])
           lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=X)
           tgl.pack(side=LEFT)
           lng.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=2)

           def allstates(): 
              print(list(lng.state()), list(tgl.state()))
           Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)
           Button(root, text='What are select??', command=allstates).pack(side=RIGHT)
           root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `variable` attribute of a checkbutton needs to be set to one of the special tkinter variables `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `BooleanVar` or `DoubleVar`. Your code is setting them to integers. You'll need to create one of these variables for each checkbutton.